# Result on another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have one `ViewController`.swift file and two View Controller on `Main.Storyboard`. Of course there is a Navigation Controller. Both View Controller have a Class: `ViewController`.

It all looks [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JWid.png)

I enter the value in the `TextField`, press Enter, there is mathematical calculation and I see the result on the `Label`. However, I can see the result in the `Label` only if the `TextField` and `Label` are on the same View Controller.

How do I make it to see the result in the Label on the second View Controller after clicking Next?

Comment: Follow this link http://www.thomashanning.com/passing-data-between-view-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass those values to the `second` ViewController.

To do this, in your `first` ViewController, you need to override the method `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` and identify of your about to segue to the `second` ViewController and set the values.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
        viewController.calculatedValue = self.calculatedValue
    }
}
```

When the `second` ViewController loads, it will have these already set.

Comment: Thank you. In new Swift only "destination" instead  "destinationViewController". But anyway it's didn't work. In line **viewController. calculatedValue = calculatedValue** says **Value of type 'ViewControllerB' has no member 'calculatedValue'** even I have **var calculatedValue = String()** in my ViewControllerB

Comment: Can you paste your code

Comment: This is ViewControllerA `@IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: Any) { 
self.resignFirstResponder()
if segmentSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
let temperature = Double(textField.text!)
let lowTempNum = temperature! * 10
let highTempNum = temperature! * 30
lowTemp.text = String(format: "%4.0f", lowTempNum)
highTemp.text = String(format: "%4.0f", highTempNum)`

Comment: of course I use `var lowTempNum = String()` and `var highTempNum = String()` in **ViewControllerB**

Answer (score 0):

Create a var in ViewController B
and assign result of ViewController A with variable of viewcontroller B.
Like
In ViewController B:
 var result = ""
in ViewDidLoad()

```
label.text = result
```

In ViewController A 
When enter button pressed

```
let vc = ViewControllerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)
vc.result = //your calculated result
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you. But still cannot win it. My app crashed right after I click my button. In line "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" --- *Thread 1: signal SIGABRT*